# WFC Service throwing exception under IIS but not under VS IIS Express

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-express

I have a WCF Service that calls a third party dll. When I run the code in Visual Studio 2013 it runs ok but when I deploy the code and run it under IIS it throws a null pointer exception. Any idea what settings I need to check on IIS that might resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the exception detail and what is the third party library?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your iis creating sub domain? in my computer, in iis express the url of the site is http://localhost:58108 and in regular iis it is with subsomain http://localhost/mySiteName/.
Try to browse to your site from Browse button and check what is the url and change the request to your service.

[image: iis].